# Why is the thin prism always in the position of minimum deviation?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

Our textbook says that a thin prism (a prism of angle less than 10°) is always in the position of minimum deviation, but doesn't provide any explanation as to why that it is.

What would happen if I increased or decreased slightly the angle of incidence? Would the angle of emergence still be equal to it?

Quote from book:
«The thin prism:
It is a triangular prism made of transparent material (glass) of a very small apex angle which doesn't exceed 10° and always set at the position of minimum deviation.»

Comment: Would you mind quoting the relevant part of the textbook in full here?

Comment: After the aforementioned quote, the book goes straight to proving some laws about the thin prism assuming that it is in the position of minimum deviation.

Comment: It is not saying that any prism is in the position of minimum deviation. It is saying that we take a prism and *put it* in the position of minimum deviation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the prism's apex angle, $A,$ and the angle of incidence, $a_{1},$ are small enough for the approximation, $\sin \theta = \theta,$ to be valid for all relevant angles, then the angle of deviation is given by 
$$D=(n-1)A.$$
This, you'll note, is independent of the angle of incidence, and can be seen as a case of "minimum deviation all the time".

How do you show this? Simply draw the ray diagram and note that
$$A=g_1+g_2\ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ \ D=a_1-g_1+a_2-g_2.$$
[$a_1$ and $a_2$ are angles of incidence and emergence; $g_1$ and $g_2$ are the angles between ray and normal inside the glass. So because of the small angle approximation, Snell's law collapses to $a_1=ng_1\ \ \text{and}\ \ a_2=ng_2.$]

Comment: But isn't the equation you provided independent of how large or small the apex angle is? I. E. It should apply for a prism of angle 30 or 45... Etc, as well?

Comment: "But isn't the equation you provided independent of how large or small the apex angle is?" No. Suppose that $a_1$ is a small angle (less than 10°, say). Then $a_1=ng_1$ is a valid approximation. But because $A=g_1+g_2,$ it follows that $g_2$ will not be small, if $A$ is large. So the approximation $a_2=ng_2$ won't hold.